# Simplest way to offer quantified visual feedback

Tags: matlab, feedback

My question might seem a bit unusual, but I trust that this could be the right place for it.
I'm doing a project for my studies in which I have to give visual feedback to subjects based on their brain activity. There are two things they can do for a reward, and one of the two should pay a lot more than the other. The usual way people do this is with a bar that increases in size. However, I find this a bit uninteresting and I'd like to make it more fun (or less boring).

Something less boring would be for example a balloon slowly going up in the sky; the small reward would be a temporary boost in speed; the big reward would be an even bigger increase in speed. Unfortunately, I don't have the luxury of time to invest in programming this, thus my question to you: what would be the simplest way to implement something like this ? It can be extremely primitive. The only thing that matters is to have something that gives the impression that it moves and that is accelerates/decelerates.

PS If you're wondering about the programming language, well, the rest of my setup is done in Matlab so if you can suggest something using that I would be really happy.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple program to make an animation of a moving balloon in Matlab.  I used a jpg image of a balloon from google.

```
im = imread('balloon.jpg'); % read in image file
im = flipdim(flipdim(im,1),2); % invert the image or it will display upside down
s = size(im);
fig = figure();
xDim = 10*s(1); % set the x dimension of the figure to 10 times the size of the image
yDim = 10*s(2); % same for y
axis([0,xDim,0,yDim])


v = 100; % the distance moved by the image each time step 
for d = 1:v:1000
    x = round(xDim/2).*ones(1,s(1));
    y = d:(d+s(2));
    image(x,y,im) 
    axis([0,xDim,0,yDim])
    set(gca,'xaxislocation','bottom','yaxislocation','left','xdir','normal','ydir','normal')
    pause(1) % pause after displaying the image
end
```

To make the balloon move faster, you could either increase v, or decrease the pause time.  Hopefully, you can incorporate that into the rest of your program.